# Change some elements at the second level of a list based on some conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I need to change some elements at the second level of a list based on some conditions.

I have the following list of objects of the same type:

```
myList = {{1000, 12, 1000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {2000, 24, 2000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {2000, 12, 2000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {10000, 12, 10000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {2000, 24, 2000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {2000, 24, 2000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {10000, 36, 10000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {10000, 36, 10000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {10000, 36, 10000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}, {1000, 24, 1000, 0, "Open", "Good", 0}}
```

Each element represents the info about concrete object. I need to modify list in the following way:

- modify only elements where Part 5 of element is "Open" and Part 7 of element is 0
- modify only Part 6 of element, change it to "Bad" if `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]] > 0.2`

I know how to achieve the goal using `For[` but may be there is a possibility to do it in functional way.

Comment: Look up `Map[]` and `If[]`.

Comment: I spent 3 hours reading about `Map[]`, `If[]` and other such stuff but cat solve the concrete question. I'll appriciate a working piece of code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `(# /. {a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5 : "Open", a6_, 
      a7 : 0} :> {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, "Bad", a7} /; 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]] > 0.2) & /@ myList`

Comment: So you mean we need all three conditions at once:`myList[[5]]=="Open"`, `myList[[7]]==0` and `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]] > 0.2`? I am confused (my normal state). Everyone of your rows has "Open" and `0` for elements 5 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
ReplacePart[myList, {i_, 6}  :> "Bad" /;
  myList[[i, {5, 7}]] == {"Open", 0} && RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]] > 0.2 ]
```